# Enable Visual Studio Code to generate constructor from Typescript class

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code to develop Angular 2 apps in Typescript. Is there any means to save the effort of writing constructors with its parameter list myself?

Would be great if the IDE could generate the constructor based on the class members like e.g. Eclipse can do it for Java.

Comment: SO doesn't do recommendations and that's the reason why I'll vote to close the question. However, there is a VSCode extention that does something like that. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DSKWRK.vscode-generate-getter-setter

Answer (score 16):

Just install TypeScript Toolbox :

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DSKWRK.vscode-generate-getter-setter

You can generate Constructor, Getter and setters ....

Comment: It is very limited, it can only generate constructor for private properties..